# Installing symfony2 plugin with eclipse indigo

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

I am trying to install symfony2 plugin in indigo Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.7.2 
using  [update site](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/).

but I get the following error, Isn't symfony2 plugin compatible with indigo ???

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Symfony Feature
>   1.0.95.201404122133 (com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group 1.0.95.201404122133)   Missing requirement: Symfony Feature 1.0.95.201404122133 (com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group 1.0.95.201404122133) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.0' but it could not be found